# CSS Changes not reflected in Frontend Magento

Tags: css, magento

I am new to Magento. I purchased a theme and installed. But i need to modify few colors in the template. I edited the related CSS file for the particular theme color (probably say ff4466.css) and also cleared the cache more times. But still the changes didn't reflect in the front-end.

Comment: Are you sure you've made changes to the correct css files? Try using Google Chrome or Firefox to inspect your webpage and find out what files are being used.

Comment: Yes i tried it again. But still it didnt work.

Comment: is it possible to let me know the steps to be followed or any other link to ensure that i am doing it right?

Comment: Clear your **browser** cache. CSS often sticks until manually cleared.

Comment: do you have css merge switched on?  if so you will need to flush the js/css cache.  its at the bottom of the clear cache page.

Answer (score 0):

if you sure that you modify the correct CSS file. if your new theme depend on Bootstrap library take care about forcing your new css rule by !important word to affect the theme. also check your new head.phtml file of the new theme to find all the CSS links to your theme to sure you are modifying the correct file or by inspecting your page